# FileNotFound Exception. Keystore File location

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

The Program is giving a `FileNotFoundException`. I am trying to find it but couldn't solve it.

The exception is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\abckeystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at packdigit.DigiCert.writing(DigiCert.java:131)
```

The code looks as follows:

```
public class DigiCert { 

    public static final String KEYSTORE = "src/abckeystore";
    public static final char[] PASSWORD = "abc".toCharArray();
    public static final String SRC = "resources/stw.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "resources/s1new.pdf";
    public static final String DEST1 ="resources/s2new.pdf";


    public void writing() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException 
    {
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider); 
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

         //This statement is showing file Not found error..
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();

        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        DigiCert app = new DigiCert();
        app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS,"First Signature", "Delhi",PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        app.signAgain(DEST, DEST1, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Second Signature", "Delhi");

    }
```

The File Location is

```
Src
   packdigit(package)
     DigiCert.java (class)
   abckeystore
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is named `Src`, replacing

```
    public static final String KEYSTORE = "src/ritikakeystore";
```

with

```
    public static final String KEYSTORE = "Src/ritikakeystore";
```

that is, `Src` to `src`, might do the trick.